# GIT сбрасывает состояние файлов

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Не понимаю с какой закономерностью, но переодически git сбрасывает состояние уже закоммиченных файлов когда я работаю в VSCode. Сбрасывает состояние вообще всех файлов в каталоге и ставит их в состояние ADD. Заметил что чаще это происходит через минуту после коммита, но может и через пару часов. Помогает git reset HEAD~ и заново коммитить. В чем проблема ?

OS: macOS Sonoma

IDE: Visual Studio Code

Версия git: 2.41.0

UPD: я ошибся с описанием проблемы. Когда это случается git status выводит что файлы удалены и все файлы помечает как Untracked

Comment: git так не делает. Скорее проблема в vscode. Может вы случайно какую-то кнопочку в гуи или хоткей какой? Локализуйте получше, при каких условиях это происходит

Comment: Пишу команды только через терминал, gui вообще не пользуюсь. Последовательность всегда плюс минус одна и та же (git status-> git add -> git commit -m), иногда использую git commit -am. Что является триггером этих событий я не знаю, это случается либо через какое-то время после комита, либо не случается.

Comment: что такое "состояние ADD"? В следующий раз выполни git status, что там написано?

Comment: «gui вообще не пользуюсь» — а файлики в чём редактируешь?

Comment: Состояние ADD, когда ты уже добавил файлы с помощью git add (рядом с файлом стоит буква A, git status говорит что они добавлены)

Естественно я код пишу в gui, тут вопрос стоял по git. GIT командами я пользуюсь только в консоли

Comment: @Darth, а ветка та же остаётся или переключаете после коммита?

Comment: @Cost, все тоже остается